# SQL Server: check constraint if relationship exists, else insert

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a constraint to validate if a relation exists

I have tried to create a procedure and then use it in check constraint. Apparently that does not seem to work.

These are my tables:

`STOCKITEMS` table:

```
StockItemId      INT
StockItemName    VARCHAR
ColorId          INT
```

`COLOR` table:

```
ColorId          INT
ColorName        VARCHAR
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_ValidateColor
    (@Color NVARCHAR(50))
AS
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ColorName FROM WareHouse.Colors WHERE ColorName = @Color) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Id INT
        SET @Id = (SELECT TOP(1) ColorId + 1 FROM Warehouse.Colors 
                    ORDER BY ColorId DESC)

        INSERT INTO Warehouse.Colors 
        VALUES (@Id, @Color)

        PRINT 'Does not exist'; 
    END;
    ELSE 
        PRINT 'Exists';
```

So if a user insert into the table stock items, I want a check that checks if the `colorId` already exists in the color table

If it does not, then insert that `colorname` into colors and. I was thinking about using a constraint check with my procedure, but can't fix the query.

Comment: That's not a *constraint*, it's a query. INSERT can have FROM and WHERE clauses. You can write `INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be Warehouse.Color.  Also check if you can make ColorId and Identity field.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Unfortunately SQL Server does not support INSERT [...] WHERE NOT EXISTS. That's a MySQL-ism.

Comment: You could use a trigger to check if the value exists on the table before the insert occurs. If it does exist, then insert your preferred or default value.

Comment: @ChrisJ is it? I never used MySQL, only SQL Server. You *can* use a query with INSERT to ensure something doesn't exist. Whether it's an inner join or a subquery, it works

Comment: Have you considered using a DML trigger?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - ah, if you mean with a query, yes, that is valid. I'm also wrong about MySQL (serves me right for trying to speed-read at lunchtime). My bad and my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an SP to check a constraint, use a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE Colour (ColourID int PRIMARY KEY, --This should really have a name
                     ColourName varchar(20));

CREATE TABLE StockItem (StockItemID int PRIMARY KEY, --This should really have a name too
                        StockItemName varchar(20),
                        ColourID int);

ALTER TABLE dbo.StockItem ADD CONSTRAINT Colour_FK FOREIGN KEY (ColourID) REFERENCES dbo.Colour(ColourID);
```

Then, if you try to insert something into the `StockItem` table, it'll fail unless the colour exists:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Colour (ColourID,
                        ColourName)
VALUES (1,'Green'),(2,'Blue');
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.StockItem (StockItemID,
                           StockItemName,
                           ColourID)
VALUES(1,'Paint',1); --works
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.StockItem (StockItemID,
                           StockItemName,
                           ColourID)
VALUES (1,'Wood Panels',3); --fails

GO

--clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.StockItem;
DROP TABLE dbo.Colour;
```

Answer (score 0):

For *checking*, use a UNIQUE check constraint. If you want to insert a color only if it doesn't exist, use `INSERT .. FROM .. WHERE` to check for existence and insert in the same query.

The only "trick" is that `FROM` needs a table. This can be fixed using a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to create tables out of the values to insert. If the stored procedure accepts a table-valued parameter, there's no problem.

This example uses a LEFT JOIN to insert non-matching values :

```
declare @colors table (Color nvarchar(10) UNIQUE)

insert into @colors VALUES ('green')

select * from @colors;

insert into @Colors (Color)
select new.Color
from (VALUES ('red'),
             ('green')) new(Color)
    left outer join @Colors old on old.Color=new.Color
where old.Color is NULL

-- (1 row affected)

insert into @Colors (Color)
select new.Color
from (VALUES ('red'),
             ('green')) new(Color)
    left outer join @Colors old on old.Color=new.Color
where old.Color is NULL

-- (0 rows affected)

select * from @colors;
-- green
-- red
```

The same using a subquery:

```
insert into @Colors (Color)
select new.Color
from 
    (VALUES ('red'),
            ('green')) new(Color)
where not exists (select 1 
                  from @colors 
                  where color=new.Color);
```

By using the `UNIQUE` constraint we ensure that duplicate entries can't be inserted